# Get Manifest during translation job always returns "0% complete" until completion

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When I start the translation job of a freshly uploaded file, I want to keep track of the translation progress. As written in the force documentation, I call [GET:Manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/task3-translate-source-file/) and check the progress state in the response which is always "0% complete". I call GET:Manifest once per second until the translation is completed, but I never got a different progress than "0% complete". Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Model Derivative service can translate over 60 different file formats, and it's possible that for certain "less traditional" formats the translation is unable to report any granular progress, therefore only showing 0% followed by 100%.

Note that you can also use the [Webhooks API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/overview) to get notified of the translation progress or completion instead of polling the derivative manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am translating IFC files, I don't know if one would call it less traditional. I'm going to try the webhoods approach. Maybe, this solves my translation progress problem as well.